# Customized F1-Score for multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, multi-class, confusion-matrix, weighted-mean

Let's consider a multi-class classification problem with 4 classes: 0, 1, 2, and 3

F1-Score 'macro'-averaged is calculated like that:

```
F1_macro = 0.25*F1_class0 + 0.25*F1_class1 + 0.25*F1_class2 + 0.25*F1_class3
```

On the other hand, supposing that the relative supports for the classes are:

- class 0: 0.4
- class 1: 0.1
- class 2: 0.4
- class 3: 0.1

F1-Score 'weighted'-averaged is equivalent to:

```
F1_weighted = 0.4*F1_class0 + 0.1*F1_class1 + 0.4*F1_class2 + 0.1*F1_class3
```

Now my question is: does it make sense to consider a customized version of the scores where the weights' values follow an empirical rule? Let's say for example that I am interested in obtaining a model that predicts well minority classes, and in particular class 3. Could the following metric be a valid approach?

```
F1_custom = 0.1*F1_class0 + 0.35*F1_class1 + 0.1*F1_class2 + 0.45*F1_class3
```

I understand that considering the weights as inversely proportional to the relative support could result in overproportional weights in case of severe imbalance, but considering them like that should not be a problem in this sense.

I am aware that there are better metrics, that are also threshold-independent (e.g. AUPRC or AP) that can be extended for a multi-class problem and for which I could also apply this method, but for the moment I am interested in validating this 'custom averaging' method, so I would like to understand if it is feasible for a simple metric like F1-Score and then extend it to other metrics (like AP).

Am I missing something? Why I can not find anything about this topic on internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, there is no problem with defining your custom scores. This can be a custom f1-score that you care about, a customized score obtained from confusion matrix, or some other arbitrary formula. The important thing is, it should make sense regarding your problem.

> Let's say for example that I am interested in obtaining a model that predicts well minority classes, and in particular class 3. Could the following metric be a valid approach?
>
> `F1_custom = 0.1*F1_class0 + 0.45*F1_class1 + 0.1*F1_class2 + 0.35*F1_class3`

Regarding this, I'd expect you give more weight to the F1 score of class 3.

> Am I missing something? Why I can not find anything about this topic on internet?

Maybe you can find more people doing customizations by looking for custom losses defined on confusion matrices. People usually assign a cost of misclassification for each class pair, i.e. $C_{ij}$, and multiply the costs with the entries in the confusion matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! There was a typo in the text, I fixed it, than you for noticing it, you can edit your answer as well :)